# How can I allow the content to be appear beside the image and under the image also after the image ends?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, text-alignment

I am working on my blog posts in wordpress. What I want is the content of blog should be beside the post thumbnail and when the image ends the content should automatically cover the rest of the area I mean it should start under the image form the left?
Here is the output image: [image]

I this picture I have used bootstrap's grids system which is 6 columns to thumbnail and 6 columns to the content which is ok, but I want the content to automatically fill the rest of the space under the image? How can I achieve it using CSS or Bootstrap?

Comment: You can achieve this by this way - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Where to use the float property? As I am using bootstrap's grid system which is 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6"></div>
<div class="col-6"></div>
</div>

Comment: Instead of tow col-6 divs , you can use one col-12 div and use float left to image .

Comment: I have posted solution with the fiddle link. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap. This is impossible to do with its current setup.

Setting it to 2 columns at 50% with the image in one and all text/content in the other will display just like you have it.

You could need to set it to a col or col-12 and add the image/text in the same area.

Think old school WordPress content editor with image alignment.

Here is an example you could mimic to get the text to wrap. The jsfiddle is a working example.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      Text goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bazdin/kmn4u8xd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class= "pull-left" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width = "150">
      <h1>
          My Text Heading
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vestibulum ultrices mauris eu eleifend. Cras ut nisl lectus. Cras posuere maximus lectus, nec volutpat tellus sodales sit amet. Ut imperdiet imperdiet mauris quis convallis. Nunc erat lacus, faucibus laoreet justo ac, suscipit pulvinar sapien. Fusce id augue ut mauris molestie consectetur. Praesent eget volutpat quam, at ultricies dui. Pellentesque nec augue pharetra ex faucibus sollicitudin sit amet nec diam. Integer ut neque in arcu suscipit condimentum sit amet malesuada diam. Aliquam auctor sapien eros, ac mollis tortor fermentum sit amet.

Duis sed sagittis nulla. Aliquam vitae sodales ante. Aliquam id mattis metus. Suspendisse ultrices nunc ac urna mattis, finibus porta nibh luctus. Mauris condimentum magna a dui tempor, ut consequat mauris euismod. In vel commodo purus, vel luctus erat. Praesent consectetur auctor mattis. Morbi ac ultrices justo. Morbi posuere iaculis malesuada. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc id mauris nisi.

Fusce sit amet massa sed risus malesuada feugiat ut ac purus. Praesent rhoncus quam nibh, nec sagittis orci dignissim quis. Donec vel venenatis nisl. Donec ultrices ante sed tempus ultrices. Maecenas eget suscipit lectus. Cras sodales, est vel finibus venenatis, mi est consectetur nulla, euismod varius massa turpis eget ante. Praesent et elit malesuada, porta nulla sed, luctus massa. Mauris nec justo mollis, porta arcu porta, convallis ante.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/xeyLk1qb/1/
```